# Posting a result of $0.00 in Access 2016 Field

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I operate in a state that collects sales tax on credit card fee charges. Our business is about `50/50` check versus credit card. I cannot figure out how to get a result of `$0.00` in a calculated field `[CC Fee]`.

```
([Price]+[CC Fee])*[Tax]= Total
```

Price is `[Price]`

Tax is `([Price]+[CC Fee])*0.055`

Credit Card Fee is `[Price]*0.03`

I have a field `[CC Fee?]` which is a drop down box yes/no. If paid by check, NO - if paid by CC, Yes

In `[CC Fee]` I use the following -  `IIF[CC Fee?]="yes',[Price]*0.03, "$0.00"`

`[CC Fee]` is populated by `$(3% of Price)` if answer is YES. It will not populate with `$0.00` if the answer is NO.

How can I populate `[CC Fee]` with `$0.00` if there is no CC Fee charged?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Your `IIf` syntax is wrong - mismatched quotes (dbl vs single) and missing parentheses.

Also the price is probably a number field, so return it as number (0 instead of `"$0.00"`)

Try

```
IIf([CC Fee?]="yes", [Price]*0.03, 0)
```